# use of :hover as a simplepseudos in csstype for typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-in-js

I am using csstype in a react component library. I want to add a hover effect, which is supported through simple pseudos. Unfortunately I cannot find any example of this being used and I can't get it to work.

I have included some code below that expressed the idea of what I want to do, but I have no idea really

```
import CSS from "csstype";

export const DropdownContainer: CSS.Properties = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "3fr 15fr 30fr",
};

export const DropdownText: CSS.Properties = {
  placeSelf: 'start',
}

export const DropdownTextHov: { [P in CSS.SimplePseudos]?: CSS.Properties }  = {
  ':hover': {
    color: 'blue',
  },
}

<snipped code>

    return (
      <div style={DropdownContainer}>
        <p style={DropdownText}></p>
        <p style={{DropdownText} + {DropdownTextHov}}>this is text</p>
      </div>
    );
```

I have tried a number of alternatives. I have added the hover to DropdownText, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a CSS module in your project and improve your CSS to SCSS. For example; 

import styles from './styles.css'

and usage;

<div className={styles.example}></div>

Comment: I tried styled-components, but there is a bug in the way it works with rollup which breaks the component when it is imported into an application. I can take a look at SCSS if I can't work out how to use basic css-in-js

Comment: Did you find how to solve it?

Comment: No, never did, sorry